# Create additional D3.js symbols

Tags: d3.js

D3 already features a bunch of [symbols](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-symbol), but I'd like to add a custom one. So that I could for example just call `d3.svg.symbol().type('custom')` in my code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This cannot be done directly since the array of symbol definitions is not accessible from the API.

You can see in the source code [**HERE**](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/a10b22654c9275da1050e1513bbd834646c0bde3/src/svg/symbol.js#L49-L100) that the symbol definitions are stored in a `d3.map` called `d3_svg_symbols`. The only part of this map that gets exposed to the public API is the array of keys. This is done by calling the `.keys()` method of the map, [**HERE**](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/a10b22654c9275da1050e1513bbd834646c0bde3/src/svg/symbol.js#L102).

```
d3.svg.symbolTypes = d3_svg_symbols.keys();
```

The definitions themselves are never exposed, and so you cannot add definitions directly as you had hoped.

You can, however, construct a workaround without too much difficulty. One way would be to create a map of your custom symbols, and create a function based on the existing one for the built-in symbols. For example:

```
// DEFINE A COUPLE OF CUSTOM SYMBOLS
var customSymbolTypes = d3.map({
  'custom-symbol-1': function(size) {
    // returns a path-data string
  },
  'custom-symbol-2': function(size) {
    // returns a path-data string
  }
});


// CREATE A CUSTOM SYMBOL FUNCTION MIRRORING THE BUILT-IN FUNCTIONALITY
d3.svg.customSymbol = function() {
  var type,
      size = 64; // SET DEFAULT SIZE
  function symbol(d,i) {
    // GET THE SYMBOL FROM THE CUSTOM MAP
    return customSymbolTypes.get(type.call(this,d,i))(size.call(this,d,i));
  }
  // DEFINE GETTER/SETTER FUNCTIONS FOR SIZE AND TYPE
  symbol.type = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return type;
    type = d3.functor(_);
    return symbol;
  };
  symbol.size = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return size;
    size = d3.functor(_);
    return symbol;
  };
  return symbol;
};
```

Then, you could create a function to check if a symbol is in the list of built-in symbols, and if it's not, assume it is a custom symbol:

```
function getSymbol(type, size) {
  // SIZE DEFAULTS TO 64 IF NOT GIVEN
  size = size || 64;
  // IF TYPE IS ONE OF THE BUILT-IN TYPES, CALL THE BUILT-IN FUNCTION
  if (d3.svg.symbolTypes.indexOf(type) !== -1) {
    return d3.svg.symbol().type(type).size(size)();
  } 
  // OTHERWISE, CALL THE CUSTOM SYMBOL FUNCTION
  else {
    return d3.svg.customSymbol().type(type).size(size)();
  }
}
```

[**HERE**](http://jsbin.com/xohox/1/edit?js,output) is a demo of this method in action.

I'll admit it seems kind of crazy to have to re-implement the whole symbol function like that. It might be worth a feature request on the github page asking to be able to provide a custom map of symbol definitions that could be read into the built-in method. Anyway, I hope that helps for now.

Comment: Is this still the preferred method for doing this ?