# Defining custom D3 symbols

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, html5-canvas

I'm trying to develop a custom shape in D3, but I'm a little green Javascript wise and am not sure what the [D3-Shapes](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape) library is doing under the hood.

In particular, I'm not sure what the `default` function in [symbol.js](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/src/symbol.js) is doing or how it is used. From the little bit of JS that I do know it appears to be describing a prototype or possibly a class. Supposedly one may register additional shapes using the [symbol.type](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#custom-symbol-types) class/function but I'm not sure how I should be calling this e.g. `var symbol = symbol("SYMBOL").type(SYMBOL)` or possibly `var SYMBOL = symbol().type(SYMBOL)` or some other combination. [Issue 23](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/issues/23) discusses how the shapes library has changed from the original implementation which I think negates this [SO: answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25333832). I also scrounged the  [D3-Symbol-Extra](https://github.com/YellowTugboat/d3-symbol-extra) for clues but no dice.

So far I have the following shape definition for a superellipse that matches up to the symbol definitions in the D3 Shapes library, e.g. [circle](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/src/symbol/circle.js), [diamond](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/src/symbol/diamond.js), etc.

```
var superellipse = {
 draw : function (context, size) {
  var w = size;
  var h = size;
  var n = 2/4;
  context.moveTo(w/2*Math.sign(Math.cos( 0/9*2*Math.PI))*Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos( 0/9*2*Math.PI)), n), h/2*Math.sign(Math.sin( 0/9*2*Math.PI))*Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin( 0/9*2*Math.PI)), n));
  context.lineTo(w/2*Math.sign(Math.cos( 1/9*2*Math.PI))*Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos( 1/9*2*Math.PI)), n), h/2*Math.sign(Math.sin( 1/9*2*Math.PI))*Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin( 1/9*2*Math.PI)), n));
  context.lineTo(w/2*Math.sign(Math.cos( 2/9*2*Math.PI))*Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos( 2/9*2*Math.PI)), n), h/2*Math.sign(Math.sin( 2/9*2*Math.PI))*Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin( 2/9*2*Math.PI)), n));
  context.lineTo(w/2*Math.sign(Math.cos( 3/9*2*Math.PI))*Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos( 3/9*2*Math.PI)), n), h/2*Math.sign(Math.sin( 3/9*2*Math.PI))*Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin( 3/9*2*Math.PI)), n));
  context.lineTo(w/2*Math.sign(Math.cos( 4/9*2*Math.PI))*Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos( 4/9*2*Math.PI)), n), h/2*Math.sign(Math.sin( 4/9*2*Math.PI))*Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin( 4/9*2*Math.PI)), n));
  context.lineTo(w/2*Math.sign(Math.cos( 5/9*2*Math.PI))*Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos( 5/9*2*Math.PI)), n), h/2*Math.sign(Math.sin( 5/9*2*Math.PI))*Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin( 5/9*2*Math.PI)), n));
  context.lineTo(w/2*Math.sign(Math.cos( 6/9*2*Math.PI))*Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos( 6/9*2*Math.PI)), n), h/2*Math.sign(Math.sin( 6/9*2*Math.PI))*Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin( 6/9*2*Math.PI)), n));
  context.lineTo(w/2*Math.sign(Math.cos( 7/9*2*Math.PI))*Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos( 7/9*2*Math.PI)), n), h/2*Math.sign(Math.sin( 7/9*2*Math.PI))*Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin( 7/9*2*Math.PI)), n));
  context.lineTo(w/2*Math.sign(Math.cos( 8/9*2*Math.PI))*Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos( 8/9*2*Math.PI)), n), h/2*Math.sign(Math.sin( 8/9*2*Math.PI))*Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin( 8/9*2*Math.PI)), n));
  context.lineTo(w/2*Math.sign(Math.cos( 9/9*2*Math.PI))*Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos( 9/9*2*Math.PI)), n), h/2*Math.sign(Math.sin( 9/9*2*Math.PI))*Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin( 9/9*2*Math.PI)), n));
  context.closePath();
  }
};
```

I can get the shape to be drawn according to the default size, but I can't tweak the dimensions as one might for a circle by setting the `r` attribute; in this case by setting the `n`, `h` and `w` attributes.

```
var svg = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500);

function visualize(json) {
    var nodes = svg.selectAll("g nodetext")
        .data(json.nodes);

    var entryPoint = nodes.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + ",80)"
        });

    // var ellipse = entryPoint.append("circle")
    //               .attr("r", 50);

    var nodeShape = entryPoint.append("path")
        .attr("d", d3.symbol().type(superellipse))
        .style("stroke", "gray")
        .attr("fill", "pink")
        // .n(function(d) {return d.n;})
        .attr("w", function(d) {
            return d.w;
        })
        .attr("h", function(d) {
            return d.h;
        });

    var nodeText = entryPoint.append("text")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.text;
        })
        .attr({
            "text-anchor": "middle"
        });
};
```

To be explicit, I'm invoking this as follows :

```js
var superellipse = {
  draw: function(context, size) {
    var w = size;
    var h = size;
    var n = 2 / 4;
    context.moveTo(w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(0 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(0 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n), h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(0 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(0 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n));
    context.lineTo(w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(1 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(1 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n), h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(1 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(1 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n));
    context.lineTo(w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(2 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(2 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n), h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(2 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(2 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n));
    context.lineTo(w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(3 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(3 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n), h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(3 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(3 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n));
    context.lineTo(w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(4 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(4 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n), h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(4 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(4 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n));
    context.lineTo(w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(5 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(5 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n), h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(5 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(5 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n));
    context.lineTo(w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(6 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(6 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n), h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(6 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(6 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n));
    context.lineTo(w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(7 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(7 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n), h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(7 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(7 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n));
    context.lineTo(w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(8 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(8 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n), h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(8 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(8 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n));
    context.lineTo(w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(9 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(9 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n), h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(9 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(9 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n));
    context.closePath();
  }
};

var svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 500);

function visualize(json) {
  var nodes = svg.selectAll("g nodetext")
    .data(json.nodes);

  var entryPoint = nodes.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + ",80)"
    });

  // var ellipse = entryPoint.append("circle")
  //               .attr("r", 50);

  var nodeShape = entryPoint.append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.symbol().type(superellipse))
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .attr("fill", "pink")
    // .n(function(d) {return d.n;})
    .attr("w", function(d) {
      return d.w;
    })
    .attr("h", function(d) {
      return d.h;
    });

  var nodeText = entryPoint.append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.text;
    })
    .attr({
      "text-anchor": "middle"
    });
}

var json = {
  "nodes": [{
      "text": "test A",
      "x": 100,
      "y": 100,
      "w": 200,
      "n": 0.5,
      "h": 200,
      "color": "red"
    },
    {
      "text": "test B",
      "x": 200,
      "y": 200,
      "w": 200,
      "n": 3,
      "h": 100,
      "color": "red"
    },
  ]
};
visualize(json);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

You claimed that you...

> can't tweak the dimensions as one might for a circle by setting the r attribute; in this case by setting the n, h and w attributes.

Well, in your case you can pass one attribute, using `symbol.size()`. For instance, `100`:

```
.attr("d", d3.symbol().type(superellipse).size(100))
```

However, the problem is that `symbol.size()` will pass just a single value: you cannot try to pass several arguments, or an array, or an object, or anything like these. So, in the example above, `w`, `h` and `n` will be `100`.

If you inspect the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/src/symbol.js#L41) of `symbol.size()` you'll see:

```
symbol.size = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? 
        (size = typeof _ === "function" ? _ : constant(+_), symbol) : size;
};
```

That unary plus show us that, if you try to pass an array or an object, you'll get a `NaN`, and if you pass more than one value they will be simply ignored.

So, how can we fix this?

#### The correct tool for the task

In the end, it seems to me that your problem is simply that you're using the wrong toll for this task. You don't need a symbol generator, you can use a common function to generate the `d` attribute of the `<path>` element.

For instance:

```
function superellipse (w, h, n){
    return "M" + (w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(0 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(0 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n) + "," + (h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(0 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(0 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n)))
        + " L" + (w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(1 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(1 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n) + "," + (h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(1 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(1 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n)))
        + " L" + (w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(2 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(2 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n) + "," + (h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(2 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(2 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n)))
        + " L" + (w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(3 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(3 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n) + "," + (h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(3 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(3 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n)))
        + " L" + (w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(4 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(4 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n) + "," + (h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(4 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(4 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n)))
        + " L" + (w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(5 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(5 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n) + "," + (h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(5 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(5 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n)))
        + " L" + (w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(6 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(6 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n) + "," + (h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(6 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(6 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n)))
        + " L" + (w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(7 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(7 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n) + "," + (h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(7 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(7 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n)))
        + " L" + (w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(8 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(8 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n) + "," + (h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(8 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(8 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n)))
        + " L" + (w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(9 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(9 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n) + "," + (h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(9 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(9 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n)));
};
```

That way you can get the `w`, `h` and `n` properties defined in the datum object and pass them to the function without any problem.

Here is a demo with your data:

```js
function superellipse (w, h, n){
 return "M" + (w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(0 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(0 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n) + "," + (h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(0 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(0 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n)))
  + " L" + (w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(1 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(1 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n) + "," + (h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(1 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(1 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n)))
  + " L" + (w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(2 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(2 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n) + "," + (h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(2 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(2 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n)))
  + " L" + (w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(3 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(3 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n) + "," + (h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(3 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(3 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n)))
  + " L" + (w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(4 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(4 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n) + "," + (h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(4 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(4 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n)))
  + " L" + (w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(5 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(5 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n) + "," + (h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(5 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(5 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n)))
  + " L" + (w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(6 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(6 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n) + "," + (h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(6 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(6 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n)))
  + " L" + (w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(7 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(7 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n) + "," + (h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(7 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(7 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n)))
  + " L" + (w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(8 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(8 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n) + "," + (h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(8 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(8 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n)))
  + " L" + (w / 2 * Math.sign(Math.cos(9 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(9 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n) + "," + (h / 2 * Math.sign(Math.sin(9 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)) * Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(9 / 9 * 2 * Math.PI)), n)));
};

var svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 500);

function visualize(json) {
  var nodes = svg.selectAll("g nodetext")
    .data(json.nodes);

  var entryPoint = nodes.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"
    });

  var nodeShape = entryPoint.append("path")
    .attr("d", function(d){
     return superellipse(d.w, d.h, d.n)
    })
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .attr("fill", "pink");

  var nodeText = entryPoint.append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.text;
    })
    .attr({
      "text-anchor": "middle"
    });
}

var json = {
  "nodes": [{
      "text": "test A",
      "x": 100,
      "y": 100,
      "w": 200,
      "n": 0.5,
      "h": 200,
      "color": "red"
    },
    {
      "text": "test B",
      "x": 300,
      "y": 100,
      "w": 200,
      "n": 3,
      "h": 100,
      "color": "red"
    },
  ]
};
visualize(json);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Oh nice, that helps me quite a lot, thank you :D (My JavaScript is a touch rubbish). Although I'm still unsure as to how one might integrate the symbol as a D3-Shape though, I mean the persons writing the `D3-Symbols-Extra` library seem to have worked it out somewhat but they're using the same magic that D3 does and I don't fully get how that mechanism works. How are they using the `default` function from `symbol.js` and how should one register a shape as per the referenced D3 documentation using `symbol.type`.